# How to add an additional wrapper div within a Views row?

Tags: views, theming

I have a [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) page with a format of ‘unformatted list’. For a views row I’d like to add an additional div to act as an additional wrapper. The resulting mark-up would then look like

```
<div class=“views-row views-row-1”><div class=“myWrap”>
```

I’ve looked in the various views template files located in the views module folder within the view module but am not seeing a place to add such a div.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

I guess I could use an HTML list and make that work but I’d prefer what i just described above.

Answer (score 3):

This could be done in a couple of ways depending on your requirement.

1. If you want to add a wrapper div to a particular row: (**Note:** This will work if you are displaying fields in the view)

   - Click on that field.
   - Under style settings select the HTML element, and choose DIV. [image]
   - You can also add the class to this div with the "Create a CSS class" option.
2. If you want to add a wrapper to all the rows: (**NOTE: This will only work for D7**)

   - The best way to do this is via a views template. Click on the "Advanced" section on the right hand side.
   - Click on the "Theme information"
     [image: advanced setting]
   - Select "Views row style output"[image: views row style]
   - Copy the template content.
   - Create a template with the name provided against "Row style output" link in the screenshot above. Paste the content into it.
   - Add an extra div element in the template directly.
   - **Note:** The template overrides are provided from "generic" to specific" if you go from left to right. E.g. `views-view-fields.tpl.php` would get applied to all the rows of *all* the views, and the specificity of the templates goes on increasing as you go right of the "Theme information".

Comment: The 1st part of your answer adds div to the field, and not the row. Also, note that the 2nd part of your answer is for Drupal 7 as Drupal 8 has no theme info link.

Comment: @NoSssweat Thanks for pointing out! Edited the first part to product exactly the same output as mentioned in OP. And added a note to the 2nd part.

Comment: I guess you are interpreting the Q title `within a views row` differently. When he says that, I assume hes talking about wrapping the entire row. But I can see that as being interpreted as wanting to wrap a field, since field is inside row.

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes, field is inside the row. My solution is as per the markup provided in the OP `<div class=“views-row views-row-1”><div class=“myWrap”>`

Comment: thank you but i tried those 2 options but it was not what was needed.

Answer (score 1):

**The solution below will wrap all your rows inside your class, as long as you are not using the `views-row view-row-1` classes for something specific, this will work too**

You can add a row class by clicking on the `Settings` link that its beside `Unformatted List`

[image]

This will output:

```
<div class=“views-row views-row-1 example”>
```

then doing `.example { border: solid red; }` will add red border to all your rows.

Comment: As per OP, an extra wrapper div is required to the views row; and not extra class.

Comment: @AjitS it will accomplish the same thing as long as OPer isn't using `views-row` for something.

Comment: Cannot be sure that it *will*, it just *might*. However, the requirement of the OP is different. You can suggest that this is an alternative approach that could be considered. I personally will go with this approach rather than adding on extra markup on top of all the markup views already provides.